# What's the best frugal way to move from CA to NY?

Tags: united-states, california, new-york, moving, frugal

What's the best frugal way to move from CA to NY? I am not moving furniture and I plan on driving my car, a prius, across country. I mainly have clothes, shoes, some small odds and ends, and electronics (laptops, computer desktop parts). I've gotten quotes from moving companies that range from $1200-$1600 which seems way too expensive. Admittedly, I have around a closet and a half of clothes (115 hangers). And I am moving across the country. I have to pay for the move.

Items like kitchenware, bed, desk, and etc I am just selling and buying new. Specifically I am moving from the Bay Area to Bronx, NY. If this isn't the right place to ask this question, please kindly tell me and suggest a new spot. I'll move it!

Sadly, many moving companies (as in all that I have spoken to over the phone, 8), charge a minimum. Generally it’s volume-based pricing unless you have some exceedingly heavy items, then you get charged extra. The minimum is generally 200 cubic feet. I say generally because that is my experience with all of the companies I have thoroughly looked into.

Just what is 200 cubic feet? 200 Cubic Feet Shipment - basically a small storage unit.

Realistically 100–150 cf is all I need (with 150cf being on the extreme end). I can’t say I have done a rigorous analysis on the space I need. However, again, the main volume is just clothes that can be neatly folded, stacked, and packaged. Odds & ends + electronics, I am confident could fit in 3 large fed ex boxes.

Comment: You haven't specified if the electronics/valuables can all fit in the car. In which case vacuum seal the clothes and send that FedEx/UPS/USPS (or at least price that out).

Comment: If you just need at most 150cu feet, then couldn't you just tow the smallest uhaul trailer?

Comment: You cannot tow with the prius (well, you shouldn't to avoid damaging the EV system). Also, I was avoiding using the car to move items in because I was taking a road-trip/vacation as I drove through the country. I wasn't driving 3-4 days from CA to NY but instead took a 14 day trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used greyhound shipping, which is contracted out through this website: https://www.busfreighter.com/

14 medium sized boxes costed me $325 to ship across the country, took two weeks, and were delivered directly my apartment.

Answer (score 0):

You could rent a trailer. That would probably be around $15/day, so if it takes you a week to drive across the country, that comes to around $100. I'm not sure what it does to your gas mileage. And if you want to be really frugal, you could see whether you can find anyone to share the costs with.

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea to pull a trailer with a Prius.

Comment: Also, for a one-way trailer rental, you can probably triple that price, even before you take the extra gas cost into account.

Comment: You should definitely not pull a trailer with a Prius. Amtrak also has a very good shipping service but don't offer end point delivery.

Comment: @Ben Miller: Pulling a small, lightweight trailer with a Prius should be no problem.  Toyota even offers a towing package for 2016 and later models: https://www.digitaltrends.com/cars/toyota-2016-prius-hybrid-towing-capability/   I don't know whether UHaul offers anything that light, though Harbor Freight has light trailers for sale (and you can find them used, pretty cheap).  It's also going to cost for a trailer hitch.